# How to deal with session timeout (or expired token), when there is no routing on link in angular 4

Tags: angular, session, session-timeout

I have one very common scenario for the expired token as below, Kindle assists me in how to deal with this.

my application session is 30 min, now let's say, I am on one a page longer than 30 min then clicking any other page link. so it will redirect to login page. here, redirect through routing so active guard comes in the picture and check if the token is expired then redirect to a login page. so far it looks good. it is working fine.

however, lets say , I have a refresh link(which refreshing table record by calling new get http request) on the same page which just refresh table records (it is not refreshing whole page). if I am on the same page more then 30 min , and click on refresh button, how to check token is expired or not. since, in this refresh scenario routing is not being used so it won't go to active guard to check token is expired or not.

Could you please guide me on how to deal with this use case.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Was considering asking a similar question, although I want to redirect user a to a different page when the session timeout occurs.

Comment: are you talking about the refresh button of the browser window or something you have on your page which basically is your refresh link @Nikky

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

In our environment, to provide the best UX possible, users are not redirected to the login page on session expiry.

Instead, the entire page is blurred and a modal is shown that requires a password input and contains a submit button as above.

Main advantages of this approach are:

1. Avoiding frustration for losing unsaved work during redirects.
2. A more seemless re-authentication experience.

Similar to some of the answers described here - https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7195/best-practices-for-warning-of-session-expiration

How to achieve this in Angular?

1. On a successful 1st login, write the date/time that the session will
   expire into localStorage e.g `new Date() + 30 minutes.`
2. Inject e.g `authentication.service.ts` at the app level, which will
   have a `setInterval(() => checkSessionTimeout(), e.g every 1 minute)`
   inside its constructor. This approach will ensure that this method
   will run on new tabs / windows as well.
3. Create a method `checkSessionTimeout()` that outputs how many minutes
   remaining until session timeout and write it into a variable in
   `authentication.service.ts` e.g `sessionTimeoutIn: number;`
4. Create a component that will contain the re-authenticate modal as
   shown in the image above. Inject this component at the app level
   with `<app-re-authenticate-modal *ngIf="authenticationService.sessionTimeoutIn <= 0"></app-re-authenticate-modal>`
5. For the blurring effect, add a class to your body / main with `[class.blur]="authenticationService.sessionTimeoutIn <= 0"`
6. For even better experience, create a div that pushes the main /
   body, and enters the view from the top that contains this, which can
   be controlled with `<div
   *ngIf="authenticationService.sessionTimeoutIn > 0 && authenticationService.sessionTimeoutIn <= 2"></div>`:

[image]

After these, the user should not be able to attempt to do anything other than re-authenticating, and you can still use your AuthenticationGuards.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice! This answer is very helpful, however there is something I don't understand. How do you determine the "inactivity" of the session? What if the token expires in 2 mins (like your example) but the user has not been inactive or whatsoever. We wouldn't want to show that div in bullet point #6. How would you determine that?

Comment: @chris That would depend on your specific requirements, but in my case, our definition of inactivity was "has it been 30mins since login?". And unlike my requirements, if you were interested in keeping the session alive e.g for every API call, then you could have an HttpInterceptor that resets the clock after every API call. Or one step even further than that I guess you could have a mouse event listener at the global level that resets the clock as well, if your definition was "keep the session alive while the user is doing anything".

Comment: that makes sense. I guess I can combine this with a `refresh token` implementation too, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `CanActivate` route guard you might be returning either a `Promise<boolean>` or an `Observable<boolean>` or a `boolean`.

But inside the same guard file, you might also be relying on a service that returns to you `true` or `false` based on whether the token has expired or not. And this is in-turn something that you might be returning from your Guard.

Let's assume that the AuthService is checking whether the Auth Token has expired on not. And the Data Service is getting the data for you.

Now, before you refresh this data, you can again check for the same by injecting this AuthService in your DataService as a dependency and then checking if the token has expired or not.

**Alternatively**, your API can check whether this request was authenticated or not. To do that, it would require you to send an Authorization Header with every request. In such a scenario, you can employ an `HttpInterceptor`. This interceptor will intercept every outgoing request to check whether it has an `Authorization` header present on it. If present, only then it will allow the request to proceed. If not, you can do the needful by navigating the user back to the login page.